# Flutter Firestore returns error without any problem in the code

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

The following code returns error "NoSuchMethodError"

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: SalaryService.getSingle(),
  builder: (_, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.data() != null) {
      print('step 3');
      return Text(
        snapshot.data['value'].toString(),
      );
    } else {
        return Text(
          "Nil",
        );
    }
  },
),
```

```
class SalaryService {
  static Stream<DocumentSnapshot> getSingle() {
    Stream<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .doc(userId + '/salary' + todayYM)
        .snapshots();

    snapshot.forEach(
      (element) {
        // prints all the documents available
        // in the collection
        print(element.data().toString());
        // print((element.data() != null).toString());
      },
    );
    return snapshot;
  }
}
```

The cloudstore document does not exist to begin with until the user updates his salary hence the if else used.

P.S.: I am a rookie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1. It is best practice to check whether the **QueryDocumentSnapshot** returned has data, plus check whether the document reference exists first by casting it as a **DocumentSnapshot** as opposed to pull the data straight up, as in:

```dart
if (snapshot.hasData && (snapshot.data as DocumentSnapshot).exists) { // ... }
```

2. you cannot pull the properties out of the snapshot like **snapshot.data['field']** without pulling the data out first as a Map<String, dynamic>; you at least have to do first is **snapshot.data()** (after checking that it exists), then pull the fields out of the returned map, as in:

```dart
Map<String, dynamic> docData = (snapshot.data as DocumentSnapshot).data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
print(docData['value']);
```

Check this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/romanejaquez/29c26e7b1968343d9ce834f8c70032ad) for the full code (replace with your Firebase config settings at the top if you want to test it by running it on DartPad.dev.

Comment: The debug Print I added to my code returns as true fro snapshot.hasData and null for snapshot.data()['value']

Comment: sorry, I meant to say **if (snapshot.hasData)** and also actually you have to cast it to a DocumentSnapshot, THEN check if it exists. I just fixed my answer. Please check.